# Istanbul: Code coverage tool for JS on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, jasmine, istanbul

So I have a Rails 5.1 full stack project. I am using jasmine right now to write some unit tests. Jasmine is great, but I don't get code coverage with it. I am looking for a way to get the code coverage tools for by JS on Rails project.

I have used Istanbul on my Node.js project before, but can't figure out a way to use it on Rails project. Has anyone had success using Istanbul as the code coverage tool on their Rails project ?

Looks like Teaspoon is an alternative, but it doesn't work and I have already raised an issue with no fix/reply yet. https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon/issues/532

Comment: Even teaspoon needs istanbul(nodejs) for code coverage.
https://github.com/jejacks0n/teaspoon#coverage